# How to correctly display 3d model in Cocos3d using makehuman, blender and PVRShaman?

Tags: ios, game-engine, blender, cocos3d, makehuman

I have created a human model using makehuman and blender and when I used this model to display in app it looks like this

[image]

and in Blender it looks like this

[image]

and PVRShaman it looks like this

[image]

While opening in PVRShaman it shows some error similar to this

[image]

and the code I am using to display this

```
CC3Camera* cam = [CC3Camera nodeWithName: @"Camera"];
    cam.location = cc3v( 0.0, 0.0, 50.0 );
    [self addChild: cam];
CC3Light* lamp = [CC3Light nodeWithName: @"Lamp"];
    lamp.location = cc3v( -2.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
    lamp.isDirectionalOnly = NO;
    [cam addChild: lamp];
CC3ResourceNode* rezNode = [CC3PODResourceNode nodeFromFile: @"man.pod"];
    [self addChild: rezNode];
self.opacity = kCCOpacityFull;
[self selectShaders];
[self createBoundingVolumes];
[self createGLBuffers];
    [self releaseRedundantContent];
CC3MeshNode* helloTxt = (CC3MeshNode*)[self getNodeNamed: @"man"];
    [helloTxt runAction: [CC3ActionRotateForever actionWithRotationRate: cc3v(0, 0, 20)]];
```

**EDIT :** Problem :

1. As it appear why model is not looking as it is looking in blender after render in simulator(texture and skull ?
2. Why Model has no texture detail in blender without rendering it ?
3. Why there is an error file not found in PVRShaman ?

Comment: You haven't indicated what your concern is. Is it that the back of the skull disappears periodically as the model rotates? Or that the model has no hair in Cocos3D? Or that the lighting is different? Or that the T-shirt has no logo? Please update your question to be more specific.

Comment: For the disappearing skull, try setting `rezNode.isOpaque = YES;`. The issue might be changes in rendering ordering of non-opaque nodes as the model rotates.

Comment: yes problem is skull disappears periodically and model has no texture detail as in blender after render, I also tried `rezNode.isOpaque = YES;` but the result are same.

Answer (score 1):

You should also be seeing similar error messages in the Xcode logs indicating that the textures can't be loaded. `POD` files do not contain textures. You need to export them separately from  Blender and add them to your project *Resources*. Once you do so, they will be loaded automatically by **Cocos3D** when you load the `POD`.

Comment: I added the texture in the resource in resources but result are same

Comment: If you ZIP up a sample Cocos3D Xcode project, including POD & textures, upload it to Dropbox (or equivalent) and post the link here, I'll have a look at it.